# What word can express entirely or partially losing a narrower perceptual experience as a result of its contextualization within a broader one?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am seeking a word or phrase, likely a verb, to express entirely or partially losing a narrower perceptual experience as a result of its contextualization within a broader perceptual experience.

One example might be created using a [flip book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_book); an individual image within the flip book has its own perceptual significance when viewed in isolation, but if we cease to allow the observer to view it in isolation, now displaying the book pages only in motion, then the *individual* image and its properties are "lost within/blurred into/faded into" the broader perceptual experience of the *collective* of images and *its* properties.

Another example might be moving away from or zooming out of a visual perception or image of trees, such that the individual trees can no longer be perceived and only the forest is apparent.

A non-visual example might be the reduction in identifiablility/clarity of a sound within a song, as the song plays through and additional sounds are introduced, or of an individual voice as it moves into a crowd of voices.

I think "drown out" would be a good choice specific to the audio cases.  I have tried [this](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/drowned%20out) and other online thesaurus searches, but they return only audio oriented results.  Similarly, "contextualize/lose within/blur into/fade into" don't seem too far off; they're helpfully less specific to audio, but unhelpfully less specific in overall meaning.  The verb "background" might work, but I am looking for more options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Subsumed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsume)?

> **to include or place within something larger or more comprehensive : encompass as a subordinate or component element**

> "But the public memory of the attack was largely subsumed after 9/11."